# Alias find_by queries of often used objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Mood` model which contains several moods which are seeded to the database, then they are never changed.

So, I was wondering, instead of always doing `Mood.find_by(name: 'happy')`, can't I somehow alias this to something like `happy`, and have it available everywhere where I would have the model available? Is there something in terms of Rails/ActiveRecord that allows this?

Comment: Couldn't you just define a `happy` method that does just that? Or even create all the mood methods with `define_method`.

Comment: Where should I define them?

Comment: in moods.rb. I posted an answer with my example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Ruby's `define_singleton_method` in `moods.rb`. I didn't load ActiveRecord, so just replace the `puts "Call Mood..."` with the actual call:

```
class Mood
    @@moods = ['angry', 'calm', 'happy'] 
    @@moods.each { |mood| define_singleton_method(mood.to_sym) { puts "Call Mood.find_by(name: #{mood}) here" } }
end
```

Here's the output:

```
2.2.1 :003 > load 'moods.rb'
Call Mood.find_by(name: calm) here
Call Mood.find_by(name: angry) here
 => true
```

Comment: Indeed, this works, but to me it looks kind of ugly. I was expecting something more like an alias, on ActiveRecord level; it would make things look cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Defining a `[]` method is done sometimes for this.

```
class Mood < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.[](mood_name)
    find_by_name(mood_name)
  end

end
```

Then you can refer to it as `Mood[:happy]`.

Comment: It's an interesting approach. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Well, anyone using a `Model.[]` as a shorthand for `Model.arel_table.[]` is out of luck with this one :)